# Calling Dispose on DataColumn

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I hear often that calling Dispose() should be done every time a class implements IDisposable. But something must be wrong with this reasoning. Do I really have to call Dispose() on every single DataColumn instance I create to define a DataSet, for instance?

If I add these columns to the DataSet, does this even make sense when I want to pass that DataSet to another member function?